# spawn strace command with Node.js child_process

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, logging, child-process

Since I'm not happy with [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63458550/stream-each-new-line-of-file-using-node-js) and I got no answers, I'm trying another method to track the output of an already running program. I based this code on [this Unix Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58550/how-to-view-the-output-of-a-running-process-in-another-bash-session) and what I'm trying to do is just retrieve the log information of a program that is already running.

Obs: to use `strace` without `sudo` you need to allow it with the following command:

```
echo kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 0 > /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf
```

And probably it will work only after reboot.

This is my code using `strace` linux command and node `child_process`, where `-p1234` is the number of the process we want to track.

```
  import { spawn } from 'child_process';
  const strace = spawn('strace', [ `-p1234`, '-s9999', '-e', 'write']);

  strace.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    // I don't know why, but my output is not being returned here
    console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
  });

  strace.stderr.on('data', (data: any) => {
    // 'data' output is something like: 'write(4, "my real log", 4)                = 4\n',
    // so we need to cleanup a little bit with regex.
    const prefix = /^\write\(1, "/
    const suffix = /", [0-9]\)?\s*=?\s?[0-9]?/
    const raw = `${data}`.trim()

    if (raw.match(prefix) && raw.match(suffix)) {
      // cleaning msg
      let log = raw.replace(prefix, '').trim().replace(suffix, '').trim();
      if (!log.includes('\n')) {
        // showing msg: "my real log"
        console.log(log);
      }
    }
  });
```

**First of all:** I don't why my log is being outputed on `stderr` and not on `stdout`, but ok, I follow coding anyway.

**Second:** It works pretty fine if the program I'm running is outputing logs slowly, like one print at a time.

But when I have a sequence of 2, 3 or 4 prints it's not working. I guess I,m taking too much time to cleanup the message, so when the other `strace.stderr.on()` comes, I'm in the middle of the process and some issues happen. In this case, **I'm able to see only the first `print` of the sequence.**

I need to clean a lot of info because the message is outputed as something like:

```
'write(4, "9883", 4)                     = 4\n'
```

Which is a mess. I think maybe a command that print only content of message would fix my problem too.

Any idea on how can I obtain a more consistent output of those messages? As I said, my only purpose is to retrieve the messages that are being output by another program **that is already running**. I also tried to follow the *"log on file and read the file"* approach, but as I said, I had some [other issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63458550/stream-each-new-line-of-file-using-node-js)

Any advice, improvement, or totally different approach to achieve this goal will be very much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure this will fix the issue, but I could recommend using RxJS with `fromEvent`: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/fromevent

Comment: @Cehhiro, can you explain better how this is going to help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, my reading of the [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) man page suggests that stderr is the default for that command (look for `--output` in that page).

The output that you're getting from strace in the `data` event is not guaranteed to be split on newline boundaries.  When you're getting slow output, it will just *happen* to work correctly.  Faster output will clump multiple lines together and may split lines at non-newline boundaries.  For a quick fix, pipe `stderr` to an instance of [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html):

```js
const rl = require('readline').createInterface({input: strace.stderr})
```

Once you have that done, if you need further help parsing the output, you can use a better regular expression to parse the whole line at once:

```js
rl.on('line', line => {
  const re = /^write\((?<fd>\d+),\s*"(?<data>(?:[^"]|\\")*)",\s*(?<len>\d+)\)\s*=\s*(?<written>\d+)/
  const m = line.match(re)
  if (m) {
    console.log(m.groups.data)
  }
})
```

That uses the new named capture groups, so if you're using a very old version of node, remove the portions that look like `?<fd>` and instead of `m.groups.data` use `m[2]`.

This also assumes that a double-quote in the strace output gets output as `\"`, but I don't know if that's actually the case.

Comment: OMG! I was stucked on this problem a lot of time and this `readline()` trick did the job. Thanks a lot for a so well explained answer! I'm not a pro on regex and this certainly fits better too

Comment: If I want to accept only `write(1` at the beggining, and not all numbers, what change should I make?

Comment: Change the regex to `/^write\(1,\s*"(?<data>(?:[^"]|\\")*)",\s*(?<len>\d+)\)\s*=\s*(?<written>\d+)/`, so you're replacing `(?<fd>\d+)` with `1`, to match the one literal character.  `\d` means "any digit, 0-9".